# how to not html export src block result in org-babel

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

I'm using emacs version 26.3 with org-mode version 9.1.

how to stop from exporting #+RESULTS and export only code block.

```org
     #+BEGIN_SRC python :results output 
       print('hello world')
     #+END_SRC

     #+RESULTS:
     : hello world
```

Comment: Add `:exports code` as a header arg. But that is the default, so I'm not sure why you are getting results exported at all. Nevertheless, try it: if it works, it's a reasonable workaround for a possible bug. If it does not work, there is a bug somewhere. Is the above your whole file or is there more? If there is more, there is a possibility that you are overriding the default somewhere.

Comment: For Emacs 26.3 the built-in Org version is 9.1.9. How do you down-grade to 9.1?? If you have installed Org via `package-install` maybe upgrade. I cannot reproduce your problem via `emacs -Q`.  Only the code block is exported that way.

Comment: @NickD i tried `:exports` but its doesn't seem to work, I made the new file with only above code segment but couldn't make it work. Although `:eval` did work.

Comment: @Tobias ya i had org-mode via el-get, which is fixed and able to get 9.1.9 version. while trying to repoduce the problem via `emacs -Q` it asked for `emacs-htmlize` package.

Comment: @Tobias yes `:export` header worked as expected after installing `emacs-htmlize` now i have to figure out what config went wrong.

Comment: @NickD you I found the culprit `(setq org-export-use-babel nil)` was in my settings, thanks @Tobias for pointing out the version error.